# Utilisation d'un « ne » explétif et de « jamais » dans une même proposition

Tags: grammaire, négation, ne-explétif

Est-il correct d'utiliser un « ne » explétif dans une proposition contenant « jamais » ?

Par exemple :

> C'est la pire chose qui ne soit jamais arrivée.

Comment: je pense que ta question porte sur l'emploi du ne explétif et de jamais dans la même *proposition*, et non dans la même phrase.

Comment: Tu as raison @gurneyalex

Comment: En fait c'est peut être pas un bon exemple, je crois que l'emploi du *ne* explétif est vraiment marginal dans ce cas précis. C'est en tout cas ce que mes [tentatives avec ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pire+qui+soit%2Cpire+qui+ne+soit%2C+pire+chose+qui+soit%2C+pire+chose+qui+ne+soit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19) laissent supposer.

Answer (score 8):

Le CNRTL dans l'article sur [*ne*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/ne) donne dans une remarque (section E) en bas de page :

> 1. On trouve dans ces constructions et les constructions apparentées des séquences du type *ne* (explétif) + pas comme cela était possible en français classique et est encore courant en français du Canada: *C'est bien un beau gars; mais, tout de même, il a une drôle d'idée de se coiffer de la plus vilaine [fille] qu'il **n**'y ait pas dans toute  l'assemblée* (Sand, *Pte Fad.*, Paris, Garnier, 1958 [1849], p.128). On trouve  aussi des séquences du type *ne* (explétif) + auxiliaire négatif composite: *Il devait beaucoup plus qu'il **n**'eût jamais possédé* (Nodier, *Fée Miettes*, 1831, p.159). *Ajoutez que Marguerite était revenue de ce voyage plus belle qu'elle **n**'avait jamais été* (Dumas fils, *Dame Cam.*, 1848, p.16).
> 2. Dans l'usage littéraire, *ne* explétif n'est généralement que facultatif. Sa vitalité baisse dans la langue parlée.

J'en conclus que c'est un usage connu et acceptable.

À titre personnel, je préfère de loin la formulation « C'est la pire chose qui soit jamais arrivée », car la présence du *ne* me paraît relever d'une [hypercorrection](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection).

Comment: C'est exactement le type d'exemple que je cherchais. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

La question est intéressante, mais l'exemple est bien plus particulier qu'il n'y parait.

Voici ce qu'il se passe dans un cas simple (*je crains que* est habituellement suivi de l'explétif) :

> Je voudrais qu'il soit là.
> Je voudrais qu'il ne(*négation*) soit jamais là.
>
> Je crains qu'il ne(*explétif*) soit là.
> Je crains qu'il ne(*négation+explétif*) soit jamais là.

Le tout dernier *ne* est à la fois un *ne* de négation ([*nōn*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non#Latin) latin) et un *ne* explétif ([*nē* + subjonctif](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#Latin) latin).
Exemple tiré d'[une note](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expl%C3%A9tif#cite_note-2) sur Wikipédia :

> « timeo ne non veniat », « je crains qu’il ne [ne] vienne pas »; le français n'a pas pu reprendre cette construction à double semi-négation, propre au latin.

La même chose avec un *jamais* utilisé dans un contexte positif, adverbe qui renvoie à un moment indéfini (comme dans ton exemple).

> A-t-il jamais eu la possibilité de le faire ?
> Oui, je crains qu'il l'ait [<s>jamais</s>] eu.
>
> N'a-t-il jamais eu la possibilité de le faire ?
> Non, je crains qu'il ne l'ait jamais eu.

Le *jamais* « positif » dans une affirmation disparait en général. Instinctivement je n'ai pas rajouté de *ne* explétif, ça me parait néanmoins possible : « Oui, je crains qu'il ne l'ait eu », et par ailleurs d'autres exemples issus de la littérature ont déjà été donnés [par Alexandre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6630/79), mais ça deviendrait limite ambigu dans d'autres contextes. En particulier, ce serait certainement une très mauvaise idée de faire apparaitre à la fois le *ne* et le *jamais*, car les réponses affirmative et négative seraient confondues. C'est dû au fait que le *ne* et le *non* latin sont confondus en français.

J'en viens maintenant à l'exemple de départ. Dans des constructions comparatives l'usage de l'explétif est assez courant (même s'il se perd dans le langage parlé), en voici un exemple extrait de Wikipédia :

> Il a travaillé aujourd’hui plus longtemps qu’il n’a coutume de le faire.

Par contre, avec une construction superlative le *ne* explétif n'est a priori pas d'usage (et ça semble [confirmé par ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pire+qui+soit%2Cpire+qui+ne+soit%2C+pire+chose+qui+soit%2C+pire+chose+qui+ne+soit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19)).

> C'est la pire chose que j'aie faite.
>
> C'est la pire chose qui soit (jamais) arrivée.

La question du *ne* + *jamais* ne se pose donc pas pour l'exemple de départ, même si au subjonctif, le *jamais* « positif » apparait fréquemment. Si elle se posait, la configuration serait la même que dans l'exemple précédent, même si l'ambiguïté n'est pas aussi critique : on compare rarement des choses qui ne sont pas arrivées.