# Meaning of "ne soit"

Tags: traduction, verbes, subjonctif

I'm confused with the following sentence:

> Ses proches craignent qu'il *ne soit torturé* s'il est renvoyé en Ouzbékistan, d'autant plus qu'il est homosexuel, et qu'il peut à ce titre être condamné à une peine allant jusqu'à 3 ans de prison

Google says it means

> They are concerned that he will be tortured if returned to Uzbekistan...

So what's *ne soit* means here? Is there a better translation?
Thank you!

Comment: The ne explétif here can be translated as; might be tortured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Soit* is the subjunctive of *être*. *Craindre*, that is used in the main clause, is one of the verbs expressing fear (or doubt), that require the use of the subjunctive.

To say his family were sure we would use the indicative (and a different verb) : *ses proches savent qu'il sera torturé*.

*Ne* in this sentence is optional. It is not part of the negation but it is often used after *craindre* in formal written French. It is called *ne explétif*. You can read the answers to [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6627/358) on French Language aout the *ne explétif*.

Google translation could be better since "will" does not show the action is uncertain.*

* <sub>I would say: "They fear he might be tortured if returned to Uzbekistan"</sub>

Answer (score 1):

A better translation could be :

> His relatives are scared that he can be tortured if he is sent back to Uzbekistan...

Comment: Not can be tortured: he might be tortured. Can is wrong here. Sorry.

Comment: I think that 'can be' and 'might be' are equivalent (but I'm not a native english speaker).

Comment: @Fernando There are nuances in the modality of *can* that prevent its being used here. In particular, *can* appears to express that something is physically possible. Of course torture is physically possible, but whether it *might* or *might not* happen is a different question.

Comment: Thanks, I see now the difference between can/may could/might.